# Thunderbird setup for two people

Tags: email, thunderbird

My wife and I want to share one computer using Thunderbird with different email accounts. How can I set this up?

Comment: Make a Luinux user-account for each of you. Each user will have it's own setup. Or if you wanna share and have access to each others mail-accounts, just add more accounts in Thunderbird.

Comment: Do each of you want private email accounts that the other cannot see? Or are you content with separate email accounts that both can see?

Answer (score 5):

Linux is designed to be used easily with different persons. Create an account for each user. When the user logs in, Thunderbird will automatically open the user's email accounts. Log out and log back in as the other user to switch to the email of the other account.

Alternatively, Thunderbird supports multiple accounts. Just set up additional accounts from within Thunderbird.

If neither of these options cut it, Thunderbird can also work with different user profiles. Thus, one profile could be configured with one or multiple accounts, another profile could be configured with different accounts. With a command line option, Thunderbird can be told which profile to use.

Answer (score 3):

If you want separate email accounts that are not private (both of you can see both):

- A separate user account is optional (not required)
- Create a second e-mail account within Thunderbird (https://askubuntu.com/a/1445570/19626)

If you want separate private email accounts (you cannot see theirs; they cannot see yours):

- Create separate user login accounts.
- In your login account, create your Thunderbird profile and your e-mail.
- In their login account, create their Thunderbird profile and their e-mail.
- You must logout for them to login and read their e-mail. There is no way around that if you want private e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

To set up Mozilla Thunderbird to allow multiple users to access different email accounts on the same computer, you can use the "Manage Identities" feature. This feature allows you to create multiple identities, each with its own email address and account settings.

Here is how you can set up Mozilla Thunderbird to allow multiple users to access different email accounts on the same computer:

1. Open Mozilla Thunderbird and go to the "Tools" menu.
2. Select "Account Settings" from the menu.
3. In the "Account Settings" window, go to the "Identities" tab.
4. Click the "Add" button to create a new identity.
5. Enter the name and email address for the new identity, and configure the account settings as needed.
6. Repeat steps 4-5 for each additional email account that you want to add.
7. Once you have added all of the email accounts, click "OK" to save the changes.

After you have set up multiple identities in Mozilla Thunderbird, each user will be able to select their own identity and access their own email account. This allows multiple users to share the same computer and access their own email accounts without any conflicts.